# Concurrent hash map case read and write on same segment

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I just want to know what happens in case reader and writer thread access the same segment of ConcurrentHashMap.

- case 1: when reader thread reads value first.
- case 2: when writer thread update the value and reader thread get the value.

Answer (score 2):

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) (You can search your specific version but doubt this behavior would have changed):

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
> overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals
> reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
> holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a
> given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null)
> retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.) For aggregate
> operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect
> insertion or removal of only some entries.

**As applied to your question:**

case 1: when reader thread reads value first.

- The reader will read the most recently put value BEFORE the upcoming put.

case 2: when writer thread update the value and reader thread get the value.

- The writer will perform an update. IF it completes its put internally before .get(), then new get will retrieve. Otherwise, .get() will not see the update and will put whatever "case 1" would have said, i.e. as if the one that occurred concurrently wasn't .put()

Comment: That's nice. But what does it mean? Also, if you are quoting the javadoc, please give a link and author (I expect in this case it's Oracle) as per [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Forgive me, I would normally paste links to source, but I was typing the response on my phone and it's not exactly a one-page find, so figured it was overkill to need to paste. It's a large block of recognizable text in widely published documents (i.e. javadocs). I searched a phrase in it just now and received this page among many others, which is the one I was looking at the time: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html - Searching for your exact JDK version might be more advisable, but I doubt HashMap's would change in such a significant way.

Comment: Per your second question, I'm not sure I can expound better than the docs but I will try. To me the statement "Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset" really clarified it for me. I interpret this as, if you enter into a race condition as is the question I read in the OP, the key differentiator seems to be the last fully completed put() would be visible by the next get(). Which implies if you're mid . put() you might get an old .get() whilst another .put() is mid-way complete.

Comment: I think you'll need to edit your post when you get to a computer then :) I'm pretty sure the link need to be in the post and the text presented as a quote. What about how the concurrent hash map does it? It it by not locking or by copy-on-write or some other way?

Comment: Right. That's the source where I quoted from. To your follow-up, the JavaDoc says: ". However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking," - So I guess that's a no on locking .I think copy-on-write would be another backing implementation, not this one, but I'm starting to speculate, and I think I've stared at this doc too long today, which is why I posted it for those more interested in the details. :)

Comment: Answer updated to attempt to apply the logic to the OP's question cases.